# Multiple transactions using FirebirdSQL (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, transactions, firebird

I have a WinForms application that connects to Firebird 2.5 DB using FirebirdSQL.
In this application I have a FBConnection that I'm using for interaction with DB and a control that provides UI for editing DB - buttons, textboxes, etc. with various event handlers. 
When this control loads I'm creating a new transaction by calling BeginTransaction() method of FBConnection instance.
So when user interacts with controls(buttons) I'm calling methods for changing values in DB (by calling stored procedures or executing SQL statements) like so:

```
FbCommand command = new FbCommand(cmd_text, connection);
command.Transaction = transaction;
FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

When user decides to apply all changes that he made to the DB, he clicks "Apply" button on my control, that calls transaction.Commit() or "Cancel" button that calls transaction.Rollback().

This worked fine but suddenly I faced a problem regarding using multiple transactions in my application. In a case of multiple editing controls used at the same time in one application it appears that you can't create and use multiple transactions within one connection.

My problem is - I don't know how to create multiple parallel transactions using one connection. I'm starting to believe that it's impossible with FirebirdSQL. It seems like the only solution is to create new connection to DB for each active transaction but I don't really like this way.

If I'm wrong about using of transactions in FirebirdSQL or anyone knows how resolve my issue rather than creating multiple connections to DB I'll appreciate the advice.

Comment: What's the problem in simply using one Connection per Transaction?

Comment: One of the reasons is that opening and closing connections to DB sometimes works very slow and, maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem like a good practice to constantly create and close connections for every small transaction you have to perform

Comment: Firebird itself supports multiple transactions per connection, but I am not sure if the Firebird .NET provider supports this.

Comment: @MikhailTregubov The Firebird .net provider supports connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that option

Answer (score 1):

- Don't share connections. Create a connection per control. Let the connection pool optimize and manage your physical connections.
- Don't keep connection opened for a long time. If the physical connection will be broken, you'll lost all of your changes. ADO .NET is designed for disconnected scenarios.
- Don't use long-running transactions. Especially, don't use them with Firebird, ever.

Consider these scenarios:

- Open connection, load data from data source, close connection. When you need to change something, open connection, change something, then close connection.
- Open connection, load data from data source, close connection. When you need to change something, change it locally. Track all of your changes and submit them once (e.g., when user presses "Save" button).

Comment: What's the problem with long-running transactions in Firebird? I'm new to this RDBMS.

Comment: They can impact server performance. Firebird has a little optimization for long-running transactions - read only transactions (see `READ ONLY` option here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-set-trans.html). But, obviously, you can't change anything within this transactions.

Comment: I can't really use your scenarios cause of the stored procedures that I'm calling performing some business logic that I can't perform locally plus caching and working with copy of data prevents client from seeing and reacting to changes that other DB users make in DB.

Comment: @MikhailTregubov I don't get your argument. Firebird uses snapshot transactions by default. So you will see the state of the database when your transaction has started and not what other might have changed.

Comment: @MikhailTregubov: if you can't make all changes locally, then first scenario is for you - when you need change something, open connection, call your SP, change the data, and close connection. Also, when you're using read committed transaction (this is default) you can't see changes, made within another transactions, until you reload data from database.

Comment: @Dennis In case of first scenario there is a problem - I can't rollback results of two called SP. I have to perform all changes within one transaction if I want to undo them all in the end. With your scenario, cause of constant creating and breaking connections, every operation must be committed or canceled before performing next one. Or I missing a point?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything. That's why placing BL in SPs is an evil. Better re-design your BL.

Comment: I can't re-design this DB - it's not entirely my project. So to sum up this topic - the best way, as I see it, for using multiple transactions simultaneously working with Firebird DB with BL stored in DB is to use connection pool, using separate connection for each transaction needed in project.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird (and Interbase, of course, also) supports the multiple transactions within one connection.

And some providers are allowed to use this feature.

Look here: http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/examples/lcpi_oledb_net__c001__example_0017.html